# Toss coin till two heads in a row or two tails in a row. Let N = total tosses and X = N − 1. It takes at least two tosses, Im(X) is 1,2,3,···. Find p.

Tags: probability-theory

I understand how to show that X is a geometric random variable, because the image is 1,2,3,... What I was trying to do was to look at the geometric distribution P(X = x) = pq^(k-1) but could not figure out how to look at the parameter p.

Answer (score 1):

Here,  the exact value of the flip is irrelevant, it only matters if it matches the previous one, which has a 50/50 chance.    So your chance at ending after N steps is $(\frac 1 2)^X$

Comment: So you are saying that the parameter p is (½)^X, which is (½)^N-1

Comment: yep, that about does it.